How to send temp data from view to controller in ASP.NET MVC application
$('#btnContinue').click(function () {                  
     var createFormName = $("#createFormName");
     createFormName.submit();
}

I would like to send a temp data from the view to the controller as I need to redirect the user inside the controller's action result based on the temp data value.

The code shown is submitting a form, so any information in that form is sent to the server.  Is that working as expected?  Maybe you just need to add more form fields before submitting it?  For example, a hidden form field with this “temp data” value?

(Question is not clear!)
At MVC Pattern there is no direct way to access to Controller from View !
(Controller is at Server, View at client)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-8.0#mvc-pattern
You should use send a request(HTTP way, get post put etc.) to controller then act as needed according to answer from controller way.
